# Failover query in RAC

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-12c, rac

Say I have the following tnsnames.ora in my two node RAC database,

```
DIVTEST = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DIVTEST-scan.DIVCORP.com)(PORT = 1721)) 
(CONNECT_DATA = 
(SERVER = DEDICATED) 
(SERVICE_NAME = DIVTEST) 
) 
)
```

And I create a service as following:

```
Service_name – DIVTEST 
Failover_type - Basic 
Failover_method - session 
Failover_retries – 180 
Failover_delay - 5
```

and the service in running in both the nodes.

For server side TAF, Should I edit my tnsnames.ora (above mentioned) on my database server as given below?

```
DIVTEST = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DIVTEST-scan.DIVCORP.com)(PORT = 1721)) 
(CONNECT_DATA = 
(SERVER = DEDICATED) 
(SERVICE_NAME = DIVTEST) 
(FAILOVER_MODE= 
(TYPE=session) 
(METHOD=basic))))
```

**OR just have the service running in both the nodes will ensure runtime TAF?**

2. Should the service-name mentioned in TNS and the service which I create for TAF using srvctl be the same so that client need not make any changes in tns at their end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[11gR2(11.2) RAC TAF Configuration for Admin and Policy Managed Databases (Doc ID 1312749.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1312749.1)

> 1. Create Service

As you have already written.

> 2. Start the service

No TNS entry needed on the server.

> 3. Make a connection.
>
> The client connect string does not require any special TAF parameters.
>   A simple tnsnames.ora entry as shown below will do.

```
mysrvb = 
  (description =
   (address = (protocol=tcp)(host=secrac-scan)(port=1521))
   (connect_data=
    (service_name=mysrvb)
   ) 
  )
```

Of course, use the service that was defined with TAF.